# Find the domain of an inequality

Tags: inequality

How do I find the domain of the following inequality?:

0 ≤ $x^2-y^2$

I've tried to solve it but I can't seem figure it out.

Comment: Hint 1: $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$.  Hint 2:  $ab \ge 0 \iff $ both $a,b \ge 0$ **OR** both $a,b \le 0$. (hint 3:  $\max(a, -a) = |a|$ and $|a| = -a$ if $a \le 0$).

Comment: Hint 4: although I'm probably just confusing things by mentioning it  $c \le -d \le 0 \iff 0 \le d \le -c$.

Comment: I sorry but I'm confused over hint 3, I don't understand how I'm supposed to use it. I've been stuck on this problem for some time so if you could explain it by giving a solution it would really help! @fleablood

Comment: ²≤²⇔²≥²⟺||≥||⇔||≤||⟹[(⟮∧⟯∈ℝ)⟶(((≤0)→((≤-)∧(≤))&((≥0)→((≥-)∧(≥)))]⟹image({²≤²}∩{⟮∧⟯∈ℝ ∀⟮,⟯})= graph_ℝ ∘({²≤²}) ={(,)|[≤≤- ∀≤0]∧[≥≥- ∀≥0]}={[≤≤-]∨[≥≥-]} = {≤≤-}∪{≥≥-}.  To express it with respect to just , simply solve for that parameter: ||≤ for non-negative real ,  and ≤-|| for non-positive real  (equivalent at =0,=0}⟹dom_ ∘({²≤²}) = {x|⟮≤0⟯≤-|| ⊓ ⟮≥0⟯≥||}.

Comment: If $0\le x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ then either 1) Both $x+y \ge 0;x-y \ge 0$ so both $x\ge -y$ and $x\ge y$  ***OR*** 2) Both $x+y \le 0; x-y \le 0$ so both $x\le -y$ and $x\le y$.... so we either have $x \ge \max(y,-y)\ge 0$ *OR* $x \le \min(y,-y)\le 0$. ...  If we use hints 3 and 4 we should have a simple expression.

Comment: @11qq00 Note:  $x \le -|y| \le 0$ OR $x\ge |y| \iff |x| \ge |y|\ge 0$.

Comment: @fleablood Aye, "or" as in andor (inclusive-or, union), as opposed to "and" (conjunction) or "ex-or" (exclusive-or, disjunction). As for your other remarks/"hints".. I'm not sure what sort of "simple expression" you have in mind, but following some min/mix notation and cheating with Desmos I suppose you could re-state the inequality as $\min(x,-x)≤y≤\max(x,-x)$ ⟺ $x≤\min(y,-y)\:∨\:x≥\max(y,-y)$, if this is valid for all types of numbers that might apply to $x,y$ (refraining from ⇐  $x\in\{(-∞, \min(y,-y))∪(\max(y,-y), ∞)\}$, but am not sure if/how this is an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to approach it, which is slightly different than the proposed methods:

\begin{align*}
x^{2} - y^{2} \geq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} \geq y^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x|^{2} \geq |y|^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{|x|^{2}} \geq \sqrt{|y|^{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x| \geq |y|
\end{align*}

Comment: Going from from $(\operatorname{abs}(x))^2≥(\operatorname{abs}(y))^2$ to  $√(|x|^2)≥√(|y|^2)$ could perhaps be supplemented with intermediate $√(|±x|^2)≥√(|±y|^2)$ (if intending to progress beyond $|x|≥|y|$). How would you continue from there? What *is* the simplified 'domain' of this inequality considered?

Comment: [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Please read, Atila.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for the comment. I am going to consider it in future posts.

Comment: Thanks, @ÁtilaCorreia.